# Moving object from Queue into Stack

Tags: java, stack, queue

So I have a Queue(implemented by linked list) full of "Car" objects. 
My main goal is to transfer each object from the Queue into stacks dependent on the object's "num" parameter.

One of the "Car" object's parameters in its constructor is "num".
I want to say something like

```
if(the object @ head of queue's "num" == 2)
{
Stack1.push(queue.remove());
}
```

But it wont let me do "if( queue.peek().num==2")

So any ideas? 
(by the way its Java's version of a queue not a custom one. )

Comment: *Why* won't it let you do that? What error are you getting?

Comment: You'll need to show us your `Car` class and possibly the implementation of `peek`.  I'm guessing that the `num` attribute in `Car` is not accessible, but you haven't provided enough information to know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not using generics properly to let the compiler know that what you're trying to do is okay. I.e. you're probably saying something like:

```
Queue cars = ...;
if (cars.peek().num == 2) ...
```

which is identical to

```
Queue cars = ...;
Object car = cars.peek();
if (car.num == 2) ...
```

It should be obvious that can't work, since `Object` doesn't have a `num` field. Instead, you probably want:

```
Queue<Car> cars = ...;
if (cars.peek().num == 2) ...
```

which would be like saying

```
Queue<Car> cars = ...;
Car car = cars.peek();
if (car.num == 2) ...
```

which is much more reasonable. The type parameter `<Car>` lets the compiler know that this `Queue` can *only* contain `Car` objects, so it's safe to access the `num` field on it.

Comment: no, I have done the exact same thing, it still wont let me access its parameters.

Comment: You'll have to add more info to your question then. This was just a guess based on the limited information provided.